# Django google-maps API v3 doesn't work with Chrome when using template variables

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I want to pass latitude,longitude variables to my template to show location on Google Maps. For that i use template variables in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: {lat: {{ m_city.location.y }}, lng: {{ m_city.location.x }}},
      zoom: 10
      });
  }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

It works fine in Firefox, but Chrome(v.42) doesn't show map at all. Although in source code of generated page latitude and longitude are correctly substituted.

If i copy generated latitude and longitude and hard code it in template then code works and Chrome displays map.

Can anyone point me to why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

As Selcuk pointed in comments, problem was in decimal separator(comma instead of point). Different separators were generated because of different language settings of browsers. Setting `USE_L10N` to `False` helped.

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML source code?

Comment: Selcuk, here is generated code: <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: {lat: 37,36883, lng: -122,03635},
          zoom: 10
          });
      }
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>

Comment: Your problem is the comma used as decimal separator. It should be a dot. How do you store `location.x` and `location.y` in Django?

Comment: i use GeoDjango's PointField

Comment: Then you must change the decimal separator using Django settings.py.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, problem is in decimal separator. It's strange, in Chrome i get `{lat: 37,36883, lng: -122,03635}` even with `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'`, while in Firefox correct code is generated: `{lat: 37.36883, lng: -122.03635}` with and without decimal separator setting.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `localize` templatetag, so you can use format localisation without breaking your javascript code.

```
{% localize off %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: {lat: {{ m_city.location.y }}, lng: {{ m_city.location.x }}},
          zoom: 10
          });
      }
    </script>
{% endlocalize %}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```